# Manipulate the pivot function generated table data

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04gBl.png)
In the above image, the cols Jan-21 , Feb-21 are dynamically generated and the data is populated using pivot function in SQL.
I want to update the 0's to No and 1's to Yes .

I am using this query to get the data.

The tables mon_year_data contains dynamically generated columnsname from Jan-21 to today date.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZtKK.png)
This is the second table which we are using in the below query,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Qoz.png)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='',@cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='', @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(mon_year) from #mon_year_data FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'')
Select @cols2 = Coalesce(@cols2+',','') 
+ 'case when ' + replace(replace(QUOTENAME(mon_format),']',''),'[','') + '=''1'' then ''Received'' else ''Not Received'' end as ' 
+ replace(replace(QUOTENAME(mon_format),']',''),'[','') from (select (mon_format) from #first_four_columns group by mon_format) as tab
--print @cols2

set @query = 'SELECT PARTNER_NAME, CLIENT_PARTNER_CODE, POS, Inventory, [Started Reporting], ' + @cols2 + ' from 
                                    ( select f.partner_name,
                                    f.client_partner_code, 
                                    f.POS, f.Inventory, f.[Started Reporting], f.mon_format
                                    from #first_four_columns f 
                                    left join #mon_year_data myd 
                                    on f.mon_format = myd.mon_year
                                    ) x
                                    pivot 
                                    (
                                       count(x.mon_format)
                                       for x.mon_format in (' + @cols + ')
                                    ) AS p '
--print @query
execute(@query)
```

I am using @cols2 variable but it is not working.

I am unable to manipulate the pivot generated data in the dynamically generated columns.
I need to replace 0's and 1's to 'No' and 'Yes'.
Please help.

Output given in the print statement.

```
select  PARTNER_NAME, CLIENT_PARTNER_CODE, POS, Inventory, [Started Reporting], [Jan-21],[Feb-21],[Mar-21],[Apr-21],[May-21],[Jun-21],[Jul-21],[Aug-21],[Sep-21],[Oct-21],[Nov-21],[Dec-21],[Jan-22],[Feb-22],[Mar-22],[Apr-22],[May-22],[Jun-22],[Jul-22],[Aug-22],[Sep-22],[Oct-22],[Nov-22],[Dec-22] from 
                                ( select f.partner_name,
                                f.client_partner_code, 
                                f.POS, f.Inventory, f.[Started Reporting], f.mon_format
                                from #first_four_columns f 
                                left join #mon_year_data myd 
                                on f.mon_format = myd.mon_year
                                ) x
                                pivot 
                                (
                                   count(x.mon_format)
                                   for x.mon_format in ([Jan-21],[Feb-21],[Mar-21],[Apr-21],[May-21],[Jun-21],[Jul-21],[Aug-21],[Sep-21],[Oct-21],[Nov-21],[Dec-21],[Jan-22],[Feb-22],[Mar-22],[Apr-22],[May-22],[Jun-22],[Jul-22],[Aug-22],[Sep-22],[Oct-22],[Nov-22],[Dec-22])
                                ) AS p
```

> Completion time: 2022-12-27T21:26:51.1093350+00:00

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Since you are already familiar with using the print statement for debugging dynamic SQL, please show us the SQL that your print statement generated.

Comment: Hi Dale, PFA the print statement output.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is an easy way. You will just have to add `CASE` statements to your final select list.

```
select ...
    CASE WHEN [Jan-21] > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Jan-21],
    CASE WHEN [Feb-21] > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Feb-21],
    CASE WHEN [Mar-21] > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Mar-21],
...
```

Although it would be nice if PIVOT allowed more complex expressions in the PIVOT expression such as:

```
...
pivot (
    CASE WHEN count(x.mon_format) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END  -- Not allowed.
    for ...
)
```

, but this just isn't allowed. Similar questions have been asked regarding mapping NULL values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322342/how-to-replace-null-values-with-0-output-in-pivot), but the answer was just to apply the mapping to each individual result, sometimes using dynamic SQL.

For your case, something like:

```
DECLARE @mapped_cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
SELECT @mapped_cols = STUFF((
        SELECT ', CASE WHEN '
            + QUOTENAME(mon_year)
            + ' > 0 THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END AS '
            + QUOTENAME(mon_year)
        from #mon_year_data
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    , 1, 1,'')
```

and include `@mapped_cols` in your final dynamic SQL select list.